# MCE kernel patch for AMD Threadripper 3960/3970

Tags: kernel, amd-ryzen

A kernel patch exists for kernel version 5.5.   Will ubuntu backport this to the latest kernel (5.3) in the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS HWE?